# UIElement.IsVisible == false for custom control, cannot focus

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom wpf control deriving from System.Windows.Controls.Control which is doing perfectly fine most of the time.

Yet sometimes a call to x.Focus() on the control calling UIElement.Focus() returns false and does not focus the control.

After some digging I found that

```
var x = control as FrameworkElement;
var focusable = x.Focusable; // -> true
var enabled = x.IsEnabled;  // -> true
var visible = x.IsVisible; // -> FALSE <- !!! ARRGG
```

The control is rendered, I can totaly see it in the UI. I tried putting the call to Focus() to the Dispatcher, tried calling UpdateLayout() on the control both didnt help.

The funniest part is, that if I use Snnop to check the IsVisible property, Snoop reports it to be True :)

Did I miss something obvious, in my Control Implementation or somewhere else?

EDIT 22.11.2012

Thanks for the comments so far, for those suggesting the control might not have been fully rendered

```
var x = control as FrameworkElement;
x.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
var isVisible = fe.IsVisible; // -> False
var focused = fe.Focus(); // -> False
}), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

This didn´t help either.

Comment: When are you trying to execute that code? You mention using Snoop and it shows IsVisible is true but that will be happening when the app is idle - i.e. measure/arrange/render is complete. Calling UpdateLayout won't necessarily help as there are times that calls to that are ignored (e.g. when you are in a measure/arrange pass). Maybe you should just do a BeginInvoke from wherever you are making that call and focus it then - or hook the IsVisibleChanged and wait for it to be made visible.

Comment: Where is control coming from? Are you sure this is the same element instance you are checking in snoop? For example if this element is from a template maybe a new template was applied. Try walking up the visual tree using visualtreehelper or the wpf tree visualizer and make sure its really in the visual tree and that the visibility of this element and every visual ancestor is not collapsed.

Comment: ahhh ... I have the same problem. IsVisible=false on a control which is clearly in the view. The control is being rendered using override OnRender. It has no children

Answer (score 1):

Check the MSDN documentation for all your `override`s and make sure you call the base class' method if mandated.

I just had the same problem and after nearly going nuts I found the culprit: I was overriding `OnVisualParentChanged` and did *not* call the base class (`FrameworkElement` in my case), even though the MSDN clearly states:

> Always call the base implementation to preserve this behavior,
>   otherwise the element tree behavior for this element when declared as
>   a child of another element may not be as expected.

After adding the call to `base.OnVisualParentChanged` the `IsVisible` property and the `IsVisibleChanged` event started to behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When did you check IsVisible to see it false ? Was the control fully initialized and loaded ? If snoop see it as true, then it must be :) And when do you try to focus your control ? If you try to focus it when it's not fully initialized, there can be a reasonable amount of reasons it will not work.

Anyway, try to select your control through [Keyboard.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus.aspx) method instead of using [UIElement.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx).

```
Keyboard.Focus(x);
```

Comment: Tried that already, same result as UIElement.Focus(). Yes the control was fully initialized and loaded

Comment: Could you provide a small code that would allow to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Control is part of a bigger application framework, I´ll try to isolate and reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, no idea what caused it. I fixed it by workaround.

I set the Visibility to Collapsed in a style, then in the Loaded event set it to Visible. I realise this won't be ideal for all uses but if anyone else comes across this issue then you can try this workaround to resolve it.

```
 // Set to visible on load
 Loaded += delegate
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
 };


 <!-- By default set to Collapsed -->
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyCustomTypeThatIsMisbehaving}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
 </Style>
```

When the control is made visible, IsVisibleChanged fires and from then on, it appears to work just fine